# Incorrect encoding in Skype input

Tags: 13.04, skype, encoding

Recently I find out that text input field in my Skype is encoded in CP1252 instead of UTF8 (which I presume is default for Ubuntu now).

[As seen there](http://db.tt/1G4SM7y7) no other part of interface was corrupted and all other utilities also seems to be fine.

Can you please advice me?

Ubuntu 13.04
Kernel 3.9.1-pf #16 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Skype 4.2.0.11

```
olloff@olloffs:~ locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=ru:en
LC_ALL=
```

**Update:** Seems to be, problem relates input only. If I paste copied cyrillic text to input field it shows correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by reinstalling libc6 and libc6-amd64:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6 libc6-amd64
```

Comment: I'm currently having the same issue under OpenSuse 13.1 and Skype 4.3.0.37. Unfortunately I can't get it to work even after installing those packages... God I hate Skype!